# clojure.spec conform throws stack overflow exception

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

Can anybody explain, what's wrong with the example below?
Why does it throw the StackOverflowError exception?

```
(s/def ::tag keyword?)
(s/def ::s string?)
(s/def ::n number?)
(s/def ::g
  (s/cat :tag (s/? ::tag)
         :ex (s/alt :string ::s
                   :number ::n
                   :and (s/+ ::g)
                   )))


(s/conform ::g '["abc"])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similarly to what Alex Miller points out in [this Google Groups discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/clojure/tzQj-Tf3rKE/hLFWJFmwAAAJ), `s/+` tries to resolve `::g` during the definition.

This should do what you want, I think:

```
(s/def ::g
       (s/spec (s/cat :tag (s/? ::tag)
                      :ex (s/alt :string ::s
                                 :number ::n
                                 :and ::g))))

; REPL
user=> (s/conform ::g [:foo [:bar "abc"]])
{:ex [:and {:ex [:string "abc"] :tag :bar}] :tag :foo}
```